# Android I don't see a marker in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I read the tutorial [Google Maps V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker?hl=pt) and implement all, but when I run application I don't see the markers and I don't understand why. I want add a marker with a position 'PLACE' and I add it, but don't show.

I think that the problem is in this line:

`mMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`

Because when I add 'mapOptions()' in 'MapFragment.newInstance' the map show position 'PLACE', but if I don't add this options, the map appears normal.

Someone can help? Thanks and sorry about the english.

My code:

Frag_Map.java

```
public class Frag_Map extends Activity {
private GoogleMap mMap;
private static final LatLng PLACE = new LatLng(38.977,-9.4185);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xmlfile);

    MapFragment mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance(mapOptions());
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map, mMapFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private GoogleMapOptions mapOptions()
{
    GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();

    options.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID)
    .compassEnabled(true)
    .rotateGesturesEnabled(true)
    .scrollGesturesEnabled(true)
    .tiltGesturesEnabled(true)
    .zoomGesturesEnabled(true)
    .zoomControlsEnabled(true);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(PLACE)
    .zoom((float) 17.5)
    .build();

    options.camera(cameraPosition);
    return options;
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            // The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map.
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(38.977,-9.4185))
            .title("Hello world")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mapaovelay1))
            .visible(true));
        }
    }
}
```

xmlfile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: is map displaying in you application?

Comment: Why you called addMarker() method twice, one with icon feature and another without icon with same LatLng ?

Comment: yes, map displaying in my application, with the options correct, but without markers

Comment: Now I call addMarker() once, thanks, but don't see the marker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding  this code after adding the marker

```
 mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(38.977,-9.4185), 15));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
```

Hopefully this should take you to the Marker position

Comment: Thanks, I add your code and I don't see a marker, I think that the problem is in this line: mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

Because when I add 'mapOptions()' in 'MapFragment.newInstance' the map show position 'PLACE', but if I don't add this options, the map appears normal

Comment: Thanks, I solve the problem and the problem is that I create a new map with this line:  MapFragment mMapFragment=MapFragment.newInstance(mapOptions()); and when I call getMap() the map that appears is a MapFragment.